# How to assign multiple values to key in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I want to assign multiple values to Teams, lose and won in dictionary for every team entered by the user.

```
def cricket_teams():
        no_of_teams=int(input("Please enter the number of the teams: "))
        
        main_dic={}
        for i in range(0,no_of_teams):
            
            main_dic["Team"]=[]
            main_dic["won"]=[]
            main_dic["lose"]=[] 
            name=str(input("Please enter the name of team: "))
            won_=int(input("How many time this team won a match: "))
            lose_=int(input("How many times this lose a match: "))
            main_dic["Name"].append(name)
            main_dic["won"].append(won_)
            main_dic["lose"].append(lose_)
    
    
        print(main_dic)
    
    
    cricket_teams()
```

But when I run the code above I get output like:

```
{'Name': ['Sri lanka'], 'won': [1], 'lose': [2]}
```

I only get the result of the latest team. What should I do to assign multiple values to key?

if there are two teams the expected output should be:

```
{'Name': ['Sri lanka,Australia '], 'won': [1,2], 'lose': [2,2]}
```

Comment: Move array initialization out of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ,

```
def cricket_teams():
    no_of_teams = int(input("Please enter the number of the teams: "))

    main_dic = {}
    main_dic["Team"] = []
    main_dic["won"] = []
    main_dic["lose"] = []
    for i in range(0, no_of_teams):
        name = str(input("Please enter the name of team: "))
        won_ = int(input("How many time this team won a match: "))
        lose_ = int(input("How many times this lose a match: "))
        main_dic["Team"].append(name)
        main_dic["won"].append(won_)
        main_dic["lose"].append(lose_)

    print(main_dic)


cricket_teams()
```

Answer (score 0):

you are re-initialising empty key-value pairs in every iteration of your for loop. Keys should be created outside the for loop once